# Как в Laravel , для debug, разрешить множественные password reset попытки?

Tags: php, laravel

Работаю над  задачей связанной с password reset, приходится после каждого изменения отправлять новое письмо, но  Laravel не позволяет,  предлагает подождать и потом отправить, понимаю это сделано из соображения безопасности, но как отключить эту функцию вовремя работ ?

Сам механизм тоже  не понятен в базе не хранит, думаю использует ip адрес  сессии или куки.

Если будут силки по этому вопросу буду рад посмотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задержка на отправку писем с восстановлением пароля задаётся в конфиге.

В файле `config/auth.php`:

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60, // Тут можете задавать время в секундах, отвечает за задержку
    ],
],
```

В базе токены как раз-таки хранятся, если Вы проводили миграцию. По сути удаление токена также приведет к обходу ограничения отправки (но это не очень удобно).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]